# UWP Listview stops displaying items after scrolling more than 5 million rows

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm having issues scrolling large amounts of data in UWP's ListView class, I've identified that the bug occurs with even the simplest of setups:

My MainPage.xaml is as follows:

```
<Page
x:Class="ListViewTestUWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListViewTestUWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

With the MainPage.xaml.cs as follows

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<string> test = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for(int i=0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            test.Add(i.ToString());
        this.DataContext = test;
    }
```

[IMG: In this instance items stop rendering after the 6 millionth row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyTlR.png)

I've also noticed setting the ItemContainerStyle's MinHeight has an affect on where the bug starts occurring, so I think its some sort of rounding issue.

Anyone know a way to resolve this?

EDIT: Changed to use ObservableCollection for data virtualisation

Comment: Use pages of just 1 million items each?

Comment: There is a limitation on any surface in UWP to 2 million pixels. You need to virtualize your data to avoid the limit (what scenario requires millions of non-virtualized rows? That's going to use a lot of memory)

Comment: In my actual implementation, I'm using data virtualisation to quickly navigate a transaction file of 10 million records, the same issue occurs and the user cannot scroll to the bottom without it breaking.
The virtualisation is implemented as per:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization

Comment: Retried with ObservableCollection<int>, which should data virtualize. Same issue occurs. it seems the act of scrolling more than 2 million pixels breaks it rather than rendering alot of items.